# How can I iteratively replace values of a specific column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame()
output_table = newDF
output_table['Keyword'] = 'abgeg','abgegang', 'abgegeb'
output_table['ID'] = '1', '2', '3'
```

And a nested list that looks like this:

```
kal =[
     ['abgeglichen', 'abgeg'], 
     ['abgegangen', 'abgegang'], 
     ['abgegeben', 'abgegeb']
     ]
```

As you can see the elements at index[1] in the sublists are stems and correspond to the values in the column Keyword in the dataframe.

Now  I want to replace the values of the column Keyword in the dataframe with values from the sublist at index[0].

My desired result:

```
output_table['Keyword'] = 'abgeglichen','abgegangen', 'abgegeben'
output_table['ID'] = '1', '2', '3'
```

I tried this code:

```
def rep(kal, df):
    keys = []
    for line in kal:
        for index, Keyword in df.iteritems():
            if line[1] == Keyword:
                a = Keyword.replace(Keyword, line[0])
                keys.append(a)
    return keys
```

I understand that this function just returns the list keys, but I am not quite sure how to do it correctlyt to get my desired result.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change order of values in nested lists, convert to dict and then pass to [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
output_table['Keyword'] = output_table['Keyword'].replace({a:b for b, a in kal})
print (output_table)
       Keyword ID
0  abgeglichen  1
1   abgegangen  2
2    abgegeben  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) after switching the keys to values and values to keys in the input list (post converting to dict)

```
output_table['Keyword']=output_table['Keyword'].replace({v:k for k,v in dict(kal).items()})
```

---

```
       Keyword ID
0  abgeglichen  1
1   abgegangen  2
2    abgegeben  3
```